# How to include the packaged parent in the child (war) package

Tags: maven-2

I have a parent pom whose packaging type is `jar`.

Then I have a child pom whose packaging is `war`. I want to include the packaged parent jar in `WEB-INF/lib` of the packaged child.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand (a parent pom with a `jar` packaging, is this working?) but the "normal way" would be to add a dependency on the JAR artifact in your WAR project. But I think that you know that and that there is a problem (which is the part that is unclear).

Maybe you could use the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) instead. Use `dependency:copy` to get the dependency and copy it to `${project.build.directory}/${finalName}/WEB-INF/lib` during `prepare-package`.

Comment: It is working - both the parent .jar is prepared, and the client war is prepared. I'll try the suggested `dependency:copy`

Comment: @Bozho If it's working, what is the question then :S I must be missing something.

Comment: "it is working" was an answer to your question about parent pom with jar packaging :) I'm asking for a way to include the parent artifact as a dependency of the child.

Comment: the actual scenario is that I have this partial JSR-299 implementation (my graduation project), and I want to create a sub-project (called examples) which demonstrates how my implementation works in a web context.

Comment: @Bozho Did you manage to get what you want with `dependency:copy`? PS: I'm very surprised it's working (especially reactor builds). BTW, what is the "it's"? Inheritance or aggregation?

Comment: Inheritance. Didn't try the dependency:copy yet, a bit busy with other things :)

Comment: the `dependency:copy` didn't work because the jar isn't installed in the local repository (nor anywhere else). I thought it should be possible to obtain it by virtue of being the parent artifact.

Comment: @Bozho dependencies are resolved through the local repository, there is no way to change that.